# Import code directly into script with Python?

Tags: python, class, import, merge, include

I'm developing a PyQT4 application, and it's getting pretty hard for me to navigate through all of the code at once. I know of the `import foo` statement, but I can't figure out how to make it import a chunk of code *directly* into my script, like the BASH `source foo` statement.

I'm trying to do this:

```
# File 'functions.py'

class foo(asd.fgh):
  def __init__(self):
    print 'foo'
```

Here is the second file.

```
# File 'main.py'

import functions

class foo(asd.fgh):
  def qwerty(self):
    print 'qwerty'
```

I want to include code or merge class decelerations from two separate files. In PHP, there is `import_once('foo.php')`, and as I mentioned previously, BASH has `source 'foo.sh'`, but can I accomplish this with Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, my first thought was multiple inheritance. But why not try normal inheritance?

```
class foo(functions.foo):
    # All of the methods that you want to add go here.
```

Is there some reason that this wont work?

---

Since you just want to merge class definitions, why don't you do:

```
# main.py
import functions

# All of the old stuff that was in main.foo is now in this class
class fooBase(asd.fgh):
    def qwerty(self):
        print 'qwerty'

# Now create a class that has methods and attributes of both classes
class foo(FooBase, functions.foo): # Methods from FooBase take precedence
    pass
```

or

```
class foo(functions.foo, FooBase): # Methods from functions.foo take precedence      
    pass
```

This takes advantage of pythons capability for multiple inheritance to create a new class with methods from both sources.

Comment: Wow, this works much better than what I previously had in mind!

Comment: @Blender, see my update. Why not just use normal inheritance?

Comment: I'm already extending a class, `QtGui.QMainWindow`. Is there a way to extend multiple classes?

Answer (score 3):

You want [`execfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile). Although you really don't, since redefining a class, uh... redefines it.

Comment: +1 for "you really don't" and for always knowing the nice, easy way to do something stupid. My first thought was to use the `ast` module and then use `compile` and `exec` to, essentially, write `execfile` :|

Comment: @aaronsterling: It isn't *always* stupid, mind you. I have used it with great success to split up a Django settings module into multiple files within a (non-package) folder.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking to merge classes, but I have a use for this function too...

Answer (score 0):

monkey patching in python doesn't work in nearly the same way.  This is normally considered poor form, but if you want to do it anyways, you can do this:

```
# File 'functions.py'

class foo(asd.fgh):
  def __init__(self):
    print 'foo'
```

the imported module remains unchanged.  In the importing module, we do things quite differently.

```
# File 'main.py'

import functions

def qwerty(self):
  print 'qwerty'

functions.foo.qwerty = qwerty
```

Note that there is no additional class definition, just a bare function.  we then add the function as an attribute of the class.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just too used to PHP's syntax... Is there a preferred alternative that I should use?

Comment: @Blender. Yes. Multiple inheritance.

Comment: Yes, MonkeyPatching / DuckPunching is considered bad form, but sometimes you *really* need to do it: like when you have a class you don't control, and code that gives you that class only (and cannot give you a subclass), yet you need to add a method into that class. Ruby's ability to 'reopen' classes, including system classes, really helps out. datetime.timedelta, I'm looking at you. Seriously, you should be divisible by floats... /rant